# Starting Docker containers from PHP

Tags: php, shell, docker

When I attempt to startup a Docker container via PHP I get the following error

```
level="fatal" msg="Get http:///var/run/docker.sock/v1.16/containers/json?limit=1: dial unix 
/var/run/docker.sock: permission denied. Are you trying to connect to a TLS-enabled daemon 
without TLS?"
```

I try to execute the `docker run` command via shell_exec so the executing user, on Ubuntu 14.04, is www-data.  For good measure I tried to run the docker command as sudo but it made no difference.  Googling around for "Are you trying...." turns up a few links that may well have some information that is relevant - e.g. [here](https://docs.docker.com/articles/https/) - but I have not been able to make much sense of it yet.

Also for good measure I output the Docker command I am trying to execute to stderr, copied it and executed it via SSH directly.  Here is that command

```
docker run -h user118 -d -p 8406:443 -v /var/docks/user118/logs:/var/log/apache2 -v 
/var/docks/user118/mysql:/var/lib/mysql -v /var/docks/user118/redis:/var/lib/redis -v 
/var/docks/user118/secure:/var/secure -v /var/docks/user118/site:/var/www/html lamp
```

followed by

```
docker ps -a
```

and then browsing to that container - no issues, everything works perfectly.

I am aware that command is going to provoke comments along the lines of "you should only have one app per container".  That is not the issue here.

Am I trying the impossible here or is there a relatively simple way to manipulate Docker via a PHP script and shell_exec?

Comment: Can you post the complete command used in PHP to launch your docker container ?

Comment: See my edited question - as you can see the command is not the issue.  It does its job without a problem when run from bash

Comment: I guess when you launch successfully this command from bash, your user is root (or you have an alias for docker, like sudo docker.io). When you launch it from PHP, is it with sudo ?

Comment: Is www-data an account similar to root (uid,gid) ?

Comment: You are right  - from bash I am running the docker command as user root.  From PHP shell_exec I am running as user www-data: the "standard" apache user on Ubuntu.  In what way do you mean _similar to root_.

Comment: I mean with uid=0 gid=0, as id 0 has all the rights

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I am posting this as an answer rather than as a comment since it does in fact resolve the issue.  However, I do have reservations about the solution so I am hoping that there are going to be other answers here.  I modified sudoers by adding

www-data hostname=(ALL)NOPASSWD:ALL
Defaults !requiretty

which offers a complete resolution to the problem - I can now start up the Docker container from a PHP script.  Allv very good but I do have some concerns about loosening up sudoers in this way.  The environment in which all of this is happening is controlled but even so it does sound like a far from perfect solution.

I tried replacing NOPASSWD:ALL with NOPASSWD:/path/to/script but that does not work since what is expected is NOPASSWD:application.

If anyone could suggest a way that offers a more secure solution I would be most obliged.

Answer (score 3):

I think you can solve this by adding the `www-data` user to the `docker` group.

From https://docs.docker.com/installation/ubuntulinux/#giving-non-root-access:

> **Giving non-root access**
>
> The docker daemon always runs as the root user, and since Docker version 0.5.2, the docker daemon binds to a Unix socket instead of a TCP port. By default that Unix socket is owned by the user root, and so, by default, you can access it with sudo.
>
> Starting in version 0.5.3, if you (or your Docker installer) create a Unix group called docker and add users to it, then the docker daemon will make the ownership of the Unix socket read/writable by the docker group when the daemon starts. The docker daemon must always run as the root user, but if you run the docker client as a user in the docker group then you don't need to add sudo to all the client commands. As of 0.9.0, you can specify that a group other than docker should own the Unix socket with the -G option.
>
> **Example:**

- Add the docker group if it doesn't already exist.

  ```
   sudo groupadd docker
  ```
- Add the connected user "${USER}" to the docker group. Change the user name to match your preferred user.

  ```
   sudo gpasswd -a ${USER} docker
  ```
- Restart the Docker daemon:

  ```
   sudo service docker restart
  ```
- If you are on Ubuntu 14.04 and up use `docker.io` instead:

  ```
   sudo service docker.io restart
  ```
- Either do a `newgrp docker` or log out/in to activate the changes to groups.

Comment: Thank you for the answer.  Sadly, it does nothing useful - precisely the same message in error.log - so I am stuck with my solution.